# Botões customizados e paginação juntos no Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables, datatable

Uso o DataTable para criar tabelas. Preciso colocar a paginação no topo da tabela também. Porém, eu já tenho botões de exportar, então não consigo colocar as duas coisas.

Alguém sabe se e possível e como fazer?

Segue o código da minha tabela.

```
this.dtOptions = {
  scrollX: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  pageLength: 50,
  buttons: [

      {
          extend: 'print',
          text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
          className: 'btn btn-default',
      },
      {
          extend: 'excel',
          text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
          className: 'btn btn-default'
      },
      {
          extend: 'csv',
          text: 'CSV',
          className: 'btn btn-default'
      },
      {
          extend: 'pdf',
          text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
          className: 'btn btn-default',
          orientation: 'landscape',
          pageSize: 'LEGAL',
      },
      {
          extend: 'colvis',
          text: 'Colunas',
          className: 'btn btn-default',
          exclude: [ 0 ]
      },
  ],

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que devido ao tamanho que possa vir a ser a paginação, creio que não seja possível deixar os botões de exportação e a paginação juntas no topo.

O mais próximo que tem do que disse é: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/multiple.html